# Should I espace special characters in JSON?

Tags: android, json, rest

I send JSON with POST request to Android. And from Android side I will reproduce that JSON. But I have a little question.

Should I escape spaciel characters in JSON? For example "çöşüğÇÖİŞÜĞ". Is this neccessary? After send the JSON I will take from Android and I will make something in Android. If I won't escape special characters in JSON, can this make error for me in Android?

Here is little part of my JSON.

```
{
    "discount_description": "Some special characters. ie: şiçöğü",
    "discount_start": "2014-08-08T10:51:20Z",
    "discount_end": "2014-08-08T10:51:22Z",
    "discount_title": "İndirim Var Şenlik Var",
    "discount_category": [
        2
    ],
    "discount_store": [
        2
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to espace special characters in JSON ,  Json will handle any special characters itself

But when you see Json data on a browser youll see \u015fi\u00e7\u00f6\u011f\u00fc //Json Encoded data

After parsing the Json data you will  get the actual data. (şiçöğü)  //Json Decoded data

Comment: But in django_rest_framework page I receive `"discount_description": "Some special characters. ie: \u015fi\u00e7\u00f6\u011f\u00fc"`. Is this normal? In "Google Chrome Postman Extension" I receive `"discount_description": "Some special characters. ie: şiçöğü"`.

Comment: @ulotrix on browser when you see the json data youll always see data u015fi\u00e7\u00f6\u011f\u00fc but when you parse json it you get Some special characters. ie: şiçöğü