# How to make JSON.stringify encode non-ascii characters in ascii-safe escaped form (\uXXXX) without "post-processing"?

Tags: javascript, json

I have to send characters like **ü** to the server as unicode character but as an ASCII-safe string. So it must be `\u00fc` (6 characters) not the character itself. But after `JSON.stringify` it always gets **ü** regardless of what I've done with it.

If I use 2 backslashes like `\\u00fc` then I get 2 in the `JSON` string as well and that's not good either.

**Important constraint**: I can't modify the string after `JSON.stringify`, it's part of the framework without workaround and we don't want to fork the whole package.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Comment: Have you read this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/25198712/2524202

Comment: Why do you need the `ü` as `\uxxxx` representation? The `JSON.stringify` creates a correctly encoded JSON representation, so every server-side JSON parser should be able to correctly decode it.

Comment: not the why is the question. that is how the request must be sent, period. :)

Comment: @Mike, of course I've read all of those questions and answers, but it seems you did read mine question well enough... :) That's the problem what is in that thread I want to avoid that.

Comment: And someone please explain why the -1? I'm really curious...

Answer (score 55):

If, for some reason, you want your JSON to be ASCII-safe, replace non-ascii characters after json encoding:

```js
var obj = {"key":"füßchen", "some": [1,2,3]}

var json = JSON.stringify(obj)
json  = json.replace(/[\u007F-\uFFFF]/g, function(chr) {
    return "\\u" + ("0000" + chr.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-4)
})

document.write(json);
document.write("<br>");
document.write(JSON.parse(json));
```

Comment: Nice, much more elegant than the for loop

Comment: yes, I know this but I can't modify the string after stringify

Comment: @indriq: I'm afraid this is not possible. THere's no way you can affect how stringify encodes strings.

Comment: I know stackoverflow community does not appreciate comment with no additional useful information, but... You resolverd my pain of the day!) Thanks for that!

Comment: Can't the lower bound be 0080?

Comment: I would agree with @androidguy in that the lower range should be increased based on http://www.asciitable.com/ and the `DEL` character being code 127 (i.e. 0x007F).

Comment: Can't replace zero-width space. `\u200B`

Comment: @androidguy I believe the 0x007f lower bound may be OK. Python's `json.dumps` encodes non-ASCII characters, and it encodes 0x7f. I ran the following in Python `json.dumps("A"+"ß"+chr(0x7f)+chr(0x200B)+chr(0x41)+chr(0x7e))` and it output `'"A\\u00df\\u007f\\u200bA~"'`, the same as the script above

Answer (score 1):

This should get you to where you want. I heavily based this on this question: [Javascript, convert unicode string to Javascript escape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21014476)

```
var obj = {"key":"ü"};
var str1 = JSON.stringify(obj);
var str2 = "";
var chr = "";
for(var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++){
    if (str1[i].match(/[^\x00-\x7F]/)){
        chr = "\\u" + ("000" + str1[i].charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).substr(-4);
    }else{
        chr = str1[i];
    }
    str2 = str2 + chr;
}  
console.log(str2)
```

I would recommend though that you look into @t.niese comment about parsing this server side.

Comment: it must be done on the client side and I can't modify the string after JSON stringify

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the exact scenario, you can affect the behavior of JSON.stringify by providing a `toJSON` method as detailed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#tojson_behavior

If an object has a `toJSON` method that is a function, then calling `JSON.stringify` on that will use the result of that method rather than the normal serialization.  You could combine this with the approaches mentioned in other answers to get the result you want, even if a library doesn't naturally provide any hooks for customization.

(Of course, its possible that a third-party library is itself doing something that overrides this behavior.)